# Display a custom url for a carrierwave uploaded image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am uploading some images in a folder outside of the public folder. I create a preview version of the image on upload. In my uploader I have:

```
  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :preview do
    process :resize_to_fit => [500, 500]
  end
```

This works well, I have no problems with it, but now when my JSON api sends the model to my front app, the url parameter for both the image and the preview version is set to the exact file path of the file on my machine. I obviously don't want that.

Is there a way I could store a custom custom url for the image in a similar way as with setting the store_dir, so that I can later create a controller method that would serve these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember any simple solution for that, but I think you can achieve that by specify the url in JSON by build it manually. For example you can use gem like RABL, active_model_serializers or build method in model eg. def to_public_json which has a custom url for the image.

Comment: I am looking into the gems you mentioned. If no one else comes up with a positive solution, I will mark your answer as correct. So weird carrierwave doesn't have something like that. It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Sorry mate, there is a "url" method where you can specify concrete path to image. I used it in one of my project in past when I storage images locally but display them from external machine.

for example:

def url
  "h t t p ://machine-ip/images/#{model.created_at.year}/#{model.created_at.strftime("%m")}/" + file.filename
end

Comment: That works for the main url, for the original version of the image. Thanks! Do you have any idea how I could do the same for `:preview` or other specific versions I create?

Comment: I mean to say, when I set the rule it is applied to the `:preview` version as well. How do I make it different for different versions?

Comment: Hm.. maybe it is worth to check variable "version_name" in the "url" method. I mean, you can use case statement and return correct url for each version, hm?

Comment: Okay, I have another idea. Could you try to define a "url" method inside of "version" definition? (eg. def version :preview do ... def url ... )

Comment: Found it! It's your first idea! The variable `version_name` is available in the `url` method. I can just interpolate it in the url in the and of the string, and in the case of the original version, nothing is interpolated. This works for me. Thanks again!